# Optional route parameters and action selection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, action, routevalues

I use the default route definition:

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

where `id = UrlParameter.Optional`. As much as I understand it this means when `id` is not being part of the URL this route value will not exists in the `RouteValues` dictionary.

So this also seems perfectly possible (both GET):

```
public ActionResult Index() { ... } // handle URLs: controller/action

public ActionResult Index(int id) { ... } // handle URLs: controller/action/id
```

When `id` is missing the first action would be executed, but when `id` is present, the second one would execute. Fine, but **it doesn't work**. It can't resolve actions.

**How can I accomplish this?**

I'm thinking of writing a custom action method selector attribute like:

```
[RequiresRouteValue(string valueName)]
```

This would make it possible to use this kind of action methods. But is this the only way of doing it?
**Is there something built-in I can hang on to?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well from the exception that action can't be determines is pretty clear that **actions are resolved first then data binder comes into play** and examines action's parameters and tries to data bind values to them. Makes perfect sense.

This makes perfect sense. There would be no point in first trying to data bind values to all possible types and see what we get and then look for an appropriate action. That would be next to impossible.

So. Since action selection is the problem here I guess the best (and only) way to solve this (if I don't want to use a multifaceted single action method) is to write a **custom action method selector attribute**.

You can read all the details and get the code on my blog:
[Improving Asp.net MVC maintainability and RESTful conformance](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/02/improving-aspnet-mvc-maintainability.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use either:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index() { ... } // handle URLs: controller/action

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int id) { ... } // handle URLs: controller/action/id
```

Or just have one with a nullable param:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id) { ... } // handles both instances
```

EDIT:
Would something like this work?

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Login", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "DefaultWithValue", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Comment: I'm afraid both are GET. And I thought of using nullable int but I don't like multifaceted actions because it makes actions more complex than they should be (= bigger surface for bugs).

Comment: I still gave you a +1 because the second one (using nullable int) is a possible workaround.

Comment: having two routes wouldn't solve the problem. you'd still get a runtime error.